# Error in teletype for atom: Connecting to peer timed out

Tags: github, atom-editor

I'm working on a group project using teletype, but when one of my peers tries to connect to the portal I opened, they just get the error "Connecting to peer timed out". When I try and connect to the portal my peer created, the application says something similar.

I know this is more of a logistics question, but is there any way to fix this? I haven't really been able to find a solution.